# How do I find a specific item in data array from Jade?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

Not sure if this is good/bad practice but I have successfully serverd two sets of data (mongodb collections) to a jade page.

examples of these data mongoose Schemas are the following:

```
...
var personSchema = new Schema({
firstName: String,
lastName: String,
email: String,
city: String,
state: String,
zip: Number
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('person', personSchema);
```

and

```
...
var personQuoteSchema = new Schema({
_person : {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'person'
},
quote: Number
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('quote', personQuoteSchema);
```

I have successfully served both collections to the jade tpls and they work fine. But now i'm confused for how to do what i'm trying to do:

I am building a page for the quotes that pulls in data for the person the quote is for. In the document for a single quote from the quotes collection, it has the ObjectId of the person from the persons collection.

This is what I have so far, but i'm stuck:

```
each quote in quotes
ul
    li #{quote.quote}
    li #{quote._person.firstName} #{quote._person.lastName}
```

Because it doesn't work. I need to find a way to go into the person document referenced in the quote document and get the firstName and lastName.

This is my first time asking for help on stackoverflow, please let me know if i'm missing anything that could help you help me.

Comment: Please show how you query db for quotes. Are you using *populate*  `Quote.find(...).populate('_person')...`?

Comment: I didn't know anything about the .populate() function. As soon as you mentioned it, I looked it up and it solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's an extra step beyond just adding the ObjectId and ref into the Schema. As pointed out by @Molda, you have to use the .populate() function to make this work.

Once I saw the comment, I looked up the .populate() function, and [this page](http://frontendcollisionblog.com/mongodb/2016/01/24/mongoose-populate.html) does a great job explaining it.

So when I make the call, it has to look something like:

```
quote.find({}).populate({
   path: '_person',
   model: 'person'
   }).exec(callback);
```